# Textbox Focus in Richfaces

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces

I have make sample project of focus in textbox from [the demo of Richfaces Showcase](http://showcase.richfaces.org/richfaces/component-sample.jsf?demo=focus&skin=deepMarine). I use JSF 2.0, Richfaces 4.3.0 Final.jar and Jboss 7 server. I can sucessfully run the project but focus did not work. When I press the tab key, focus arrives at the textbox. If there is anything I need to congifure, please advise me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Finally, I got it. I put the javascript code in the jsf form just like this.
<h:form id="frm">
<script type="text/javascript"> 
window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('frm:txtStaffId').focus();
}
</script>
...
...
<h:inputText id="txtStaffId"/>
...
...
</h:form>
```